# How to flask-admin add dynamic form_choices from database

Tags: flask, flask-admin

How to  dynamic loading form_choices from other ModeView.

my code

```py
class OnBoarding(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'on_boarding'
    status = db.Column(db.String(256))


class OptionStatus(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'option_status'
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String(256))


class OnBoardingAdminView(ModelView):
    form_choices = {
        'status': [(m.status, m.status for m in OptionStatus.query.all())],
    }

admin.add_view(ModelView(OptionStatus, db.session, category='Option'))
admin.add_view(OnBoardingAdminView(OnBoarding, db.session))
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. ????

Answer (score 4):

Since your choices aren't static and require a DB query, you should populate them in `scaffold_form` or `create_form`/`edit_form`.

```
class MyView(BaseModelView):
    def scaffold_form(self):
        form = super(MyView, self).scaffold_form()

        choices = ((m.status, m.status) for m in OptionStatus.query.all())
        form.status.choices = choices

        return form
```

Comment: This would have been nice, but `scaffold_form()` will run outside of an app context, no DOM querying possible without major lifting.